# Splitting data to 2 tabs with pagination without making 2 queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Originally I had a single tab in the page that displayed the data as a table:

```
$data = MyModel::paginate(100);
```

Then, I needed to split the data to 2 different tabs in the page with different filters:

```
$tab_1_data = MyModel::where('column', 'some_value');

$tab_2_data = MyModel::where('column', 'some_other_value');
```

Is it possible to get the paginated data for the two tabs using a single query? Or I will have to do 2 queries in this case:

```
$tab_1_data = MyModel::where('column', 'some_value')->paginate();
$tab_2_data = MyModel::where('column',  'some_other_value')->paginate();
```

Because these 2 queries may slow down the page loading time

Comment: `may` is not a vocabulary you want to use in IT sphere. Do you have high traffic ? both queries are heavy ? is it a good idea to spend time to save 5ms of query ? in any case, you can query with a `whereIn` to have both of your data, then loop in php to separate them.

Comment: It does slow down slightly* . I also thought about doing what you said using PHP. But then I thought it might not work as expected. Because if in the frontend I loop through the results, I won't get the desired number of paginated items per tab right? Let's say 30 of the 100 paginated items on the first page belong to the other tab, I'll end up having 70/30 items on the tabs instead of 100 each, no?

Comment: You are right, you need to trick the query to have 50/50. Other case, just use Ajax when your user hits the second tab to query your second data. Which is of course the best way. But weird if 2 queries on same table slows down so much your app. Do you have good indexes ?

Comment: I think might also be bad indexes. But regardless just the connection time to the db twice instead of once also takes more time

Answer (score 0):

For a given collection, we can use the [Partition Method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-partition) to split a collection based on a truth test. This, however, would not work if there is overlap between the two models. If this is the case, your best option is using the [Filter method.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-filter)

You can get your initial collection by getting all records that satisfy all total requirements:

```php
$records = YourModel::where(**your conditions**)->get();
```

Then either filter down or partition into multiple collections based on your conditions.

```php
[$first, $second] = $records->partition(function ($record) {
    return $record === 'this_is_the_truth_test';
});
```

These individual collections can then be paginated to display as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```php
$data = MyModel::paginate(100);
        
$tab1 = array_slice($data->items(), 0, $data->total() / 2);
$tab2 = array_slice($data->items(), $data->total() / 2);
```